# How to test a redux toolkit slice using createAsyncThunk with Jest?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to test the following slice (simplified version without right typing):

```
interface MyState {
  data: any[];
}

const initialState: MyState = {
  data: [],
};

export const postData = createAsyncThunk(
  'data/postData',
  async (
    param: {
      data: any[];
    },
    { rejectWithValue },
  ) => {
    try {
      const myService: MyService = new MyService();
      return await myService.postData(param.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  },
);

const combineExtraReducers = (
  builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<MyState>,
) => {
  builder.addCase(getData.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
    state.data = payload;
  });
};

export const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    combineExtraReducers(builder);
  },
});
```

How can I write a simple test for this slice? I'm fine without createAsyncThunk, but I can't manage to write a test with the thunk.

The approach from the official [redux toolkit documentation](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests) does not work either. I get an error message regarding timeout.

We're using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) as HTTP client.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests suggests to test the component that is dispatching the thunk rather than testing the thunk itself: "We consider thunk behavior to be an implementation detail of the application, and recommend that it be covered by testing the group of components (or whole app) using it, rather than testing the thunk in isolation". However, if you just want test coverage for the async function you're passing to `createAsyncThunk()`, you can assign and export it on its own and import it in a test case with jest. You'd have to mock out `MyService` but that's it.

Comment: When you say the official doc suggestions didn't work, what were you using to mock the request from `myService.postData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps:

1. Use `jest.spyOn(MyService.prototype, 'postData')` to mock `postData` method of `MyService` class and its resolved/rejected value.
2. Create a mock redux store so that we can dispatch the async thunk and get the state using `store.getState()` API and assert the changes.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { ActionReducerMapBuilder, createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { MyService } from './my-service';

interface MyState {
  data: any[];
}

const initialState: MyState = {
  data: [],
};

export const postData = createAsyncThunk(
  'data/postData',
  async (
    param: {
      data: any[];
    },
    { rejectWithValue },
  ) => {
    try {
      const myService: MyService = new MyService();
      return await myService.postData(param.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  },
);

const combineExtraReducers = (builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<MyState>) => {
  builder.addCase(postData.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
    state.data = payload;
  });
};

export const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'data',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    combineExtraReducers(builder);
  },
});
```

`my-service.ts`:

```
export class MyService {
  async postData(params) {
    return ['real data'];
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { dataSlice, postData } from './';
import { MyService } from './my-service';

describe('72549837', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should post data fulfilled', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(MyService.prototype, 'postData').mockResolvedValueOnce(['mock data']);
    const store = configureStore({ reducer: dataSlice.reducer });
    await store.dispatch(postData({ data: ['mock arg'] }));
    expect(store.getState()).toEqual({ data: ['mock data'] });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS   redux-toolkit-example  packages/redux-toolkit-example/stackoverflow/72549837/index.test.ts
  72549837
    ✓ should post data fulfilled (6 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |   85.71 |      100 |   83.33 |   83.33 |                   
 index.ts      |    87.5 |      100 |     100 |   85.71 | 24-25             
 my-service.ts |      80 |      100 |      50 |      75 | 3                 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.609 s
```